# python parse evernote shared notebook

Tags: python, html, selenium, parsing, xpath

I am trying to get data from evernote 'shared notebook'.
For example, from this one: https://www.evernote.com/pub/missrspink/evernoteexamples#st=p&n=56b67555-158e-4d10-96e2-3b2c57ee372c

I tried to use Beautiful Soup:

```
url = 'https://www.evernote.com/pub/missrspink/evernoteexamples#st=p&n=56b67555-158e-4d10-96e2-3b2c57ee372c'
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
bs
```

The result doesn't contain any text information from the notebook, only some code.

I also seen an advice to use selenium and find elements by XPath. 
For example I want to find the head of this note - 'Term 3 Week2'. In Google Chrome i found that it's XPath is '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/b/span/u/b'.
So i tried this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
t = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/b/span/u/b')
```

But it also didn't work, the result was 'NoSuchElementException:... '.

I am a newbie in python and especially parsing, so I would be glad to receive any help.
I am using python 3.6.2 and jupiter-notebook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add to what @blakev said, you will not get the correct HTML you want with requests because the "#" in the URL means the bit after is not sent to the server so you are just sending and geting the response back to `https://www.evernote.com/pub/missrspink/evernoteexamples`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to interface with Evernote is to use their [official Python API](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/python.php).

After you've configured your API key and can generally connect, you can then download and reference Notes and Notebooks.

Evernote Notes use their own template language called [ENML](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php) (EverNote Markup Language) which is a subset of HTML. You'll be able to use BeautifulSoup4 to parse the ENML and extract the elements you're looking for.

If you're trying to extract information against a local installation (instead of their web app) you may also be able to get what you need from the executable. See [how to pass arguments](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enscript.php) to the local install to extract data. For this you're going to need to use the Python3 [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

**HOWEVER**

If you want to use selenium, this will get you started:

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# your example URL
URL = 'https://www.evernote.com/pub/missrspink/evernoteexamples#st=p&n=56b67555-158e-4d10-96e2-3b2c57ee372c'

# create the browser interface, and a generic "wait" that we can use
#  to intelligently block while the driver looks for elements we expect.
#  10:  maximum wait in seconds
# 0.5:  polling interval in seconds
driver = Chrome()
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5)

driver.get(URL)

# Note contents are loaded in an iFrame element
find_iframe = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.gwt-Frame'
find_html = By.TAG_NAME, 'html'

# .. so we have to wait for the iframe to exist, switch our driver context
#  and then wait for that internal page to load.
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(find_iframe))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(find_html))

# since ENML is "just" HTML we can select the top tag and get all the 
#  contents inside it.
doc = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

print(doc.get_attribute('innerHTML'))  # <-- this is what you want

# cleanup our browser instance
driver.quit()
```

Comment: for Selenium you need to make sure you install the webdriver you are going to use correctly, or it will fail on the `driver = Chrome()` step.

Comment: @blakev Thanks a lot, for such a full answer! The ''selenium" method totally works perfect. The "evernote" method has a disadvantage - there isn't official package for python 3. so it may be a little more complex to use. Thanks for your help!